# Jenkins - Deleting artifacts automatically

Tags: jenkins, build, continuous-integration, workspace, artifacts

**JENKINS**

I am noticing that the every time I run one of my jobs in Jenkins, there are **two** files created in the **/workspace/build/distributions** dir. The two files have the extensions of *.tar* and *.tgz.* Every time, I run the job, another set of these files are created. So, if I run the job 3 times, there will be 6 files all together. I have noticed that during the dependency check phase, these artifacts slow things down. Therefore, I wanted to remove them automatically before each time this job runs. I have attempted the configs in the image below. In addition, I have tried the workspace cleanup plugin and that completely deleted the workspace. That is definitely not what I wanted.

Therefore, what would be the best way to go about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What scm plugin are you using?  Some of the scm plugins allow you to clean the workspace before an update (e.g. SVN's "Emulate clean checkout" and Git's "Clean before checkout" options).

If you're not using a scm plugin, can you remove the files in a batch/shell script during the first build step?

Or perhaps you can go about it from the reverse direction.  Can you get rid of the files as the last build step of the job?  That way, they are gone when the next build comes along.

Comment: I am using the Git scm plugin. For now, I am using the rm -rf /path/to/file/* as the first step in the execute shell to delete the files. I will try to use the "Clean before checkout" option since I am looking to avoid the shell for this task and I will let you know how that goes. Thanks